# apex:pageMessages includes the entire component tree path for a apex:inputText with required="true"

Tags: visualforce, validation, inputtext

I have a Visualforce page that contains an [apex:inputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputText.htm) with `required="true"`. It is nested within several component levels, such as a `apex:pageBlockSectionItem`, `apex:pageBlockSection`, `apex:pageBlock` and `apex:form`.

If I submit the form without entering a value I get the following output in the apex:pageMessages:

[image: apex:pageMessages with entire component tree path for required inputText]

> **Error:** mediaPage:mediaPageBlock:mediaForm:dropBlock:requiredElementsSection:goalsSectionItem:goals: Validation Error: Value is required.

The component tree path is meaningless to the users.

**Is there anyway to reformat this message or do I need to drop the required attribute on the inputText and validate the input myself in the controller?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding a label attribute to the inputText field - if there is no label, the error will display the whole tree, but with a label, it should just display the label + error message

Comment: I was about to say that this doesn't work when I noticed in the docs that inputText.label is API v23.0. Once I updated it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just an assumption 
are u using try catch in the VF page and trying to throw exception ? If so are you using

```
try {               
       }
  catch (Exception e) {
```

ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Invalid Input.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);

```
        }
```

use ApexPages.addMessages(e);   instead of

Comment: I'm reasonably certain the error message isn't coming from my controller code. Rather, the validation that is built into Visualforce is raising it.

Comment: ah i wasn't sure if it was coming from the controller that's the reason i had as assumption ")